# Anchor link is not going on specific div

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I try to open following link, it does not open page with specific postion where the anchor exists

http://192.169.215.176/~nywindowfashion/product-category/skylights#skylight-honeycombs

Check this screenshot

[image]
Please help me.

Comment: Write your code here, so we can help!

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post the code you're using.

Comment: It does, but then the page gets bigger.

Comment: Did you set an `id` to the element?

Answer (score 0):

It actually does open to that position, but then moves back up.
Notice that clicking on the links at the top of the page does bring you to the right position.
I'm guessing it's in one of your javascript files, since when I disable javascript on the page, on loading it scrolls to the right position.